# httppost Android, values not pass to database for creating user

Tags: php, android, sql, http-post

I have been successful in creating an authentication using httppost from java Android code through php to mysql.  I'm having issues create a new user however.  I've checked multiple posts from other users, and I think it looks good.  Also, I've created a simple html form to test the php creation of new user, and that works too.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Here is my java code and PHP below that.  Thanks!

```
    try {
            // create new array list
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // place them in an array list
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));

            // add array list to http post
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // assign executed form container to response
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // check status code,
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                // assign response entity to htpp entitiy
                entity = response.getEntity();

                // chekc if entity is not null
                if (entity != null) {

                    Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(entity));

                    Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccount.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    // }

                    // display a taost saying login was a success
                    Toast.makeText(CreateAccount.this, user,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // display toast when there is a connection error
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ConnectionError",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

PHP Code:

```
    //get form data

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

echo "INSERT INTO androidlogin (user, pass) VALUES ('$user','$pass')";

//insert data
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO androidlogin (user, pass) VALUES  ('$user','$pass')");
if($insert){
$arr2 = array("user" => $user, "pass" => $pass);
echo json_encode($arr2);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting values are called "username" and "password"  whereas server checks for "user"  &  "pass". You have to use the same keys.